# SharePoint2013 - Custom Metadata in Advanced search property picker doesn't return values

Tags: sharepoint

I've added few custom metadata in Advanced Search web part. When I try to search using these properties, there are no results found.[This is the image of custom metadata added in advanced search web part.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCPIb.png)

[This is the result of search - Document Type - Contains - Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHsL4.png)

Comment: Hello and welcome to [SO].Please take time out for a [tour] and visit the [help]. You might also want to read [ask].

Comment: @user6602250: have you run the Full Crawl after adding new metadata ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create managed properties.(map with appropriate crawled properties). Start Full crawl.Use this managed property in advance search box.